# Gradients of scalar functions

Tags: vector-analysis

Looking at some of the definitions of gradient (for a scalar function $f(\mathbf{r}(u)))$;
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}} = \nabla f $$ 
(from http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/0471705195.app3/pdf)
$$\mathrm{d}f = \nabla f \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$$
(usual definition)

Now if I look at the Chain rule, we know;
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{du} = \nabla f \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}}{du}$$

Now from here on is my own working;
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{du} = \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{d\mathbf{r}} \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}}{du} = \nabla f \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}}{du}$$
Which is not the same as above.

Can someone explain what I have done that is wrong,  and why it is wrong?

Comment: When you say $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{du} = \dots= \nabla f \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}}{du}$, what exactly do you mean by the multiplication on the right?

Comment: On the left, df/du is a scalar value.  On the right the product of two vectors.  That product *must* be the dot product of the two vectors.